# How to comment out before and after a line of a certain pattern in Java file?

Tags: java, sed

I need to comment out lines in several hundred Java files. It is easy to comment out a single line like this:

```
sed 's-PATTERN-//PATTERN-' src/main/java/com/Test/test.java
```

I was wondering if it is possible to comment out the previous and the next line before and after the match.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this. I think there is a reason Java does not support c++ style macros. Wouldn't you be better off making your java class take some configuration object at runtime rather than munging the .java file prior to compilation.

Comment: `/PATTERN/s-^-//-` comments out the line matching PATTERN.  The suggestion of `s-PATTERN-//&-` would not necessarily comment out the entire line.  The solutions below differ in their expectations of whether PATTERN is the entire line or not... what do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Perl:

```
perl -0pe 's!(.*)\n(PATTERN)\n(.*)!//$1\n//$2\n//$3!g' file.java
```

This writes the modified file to stdout. Either wrap this in shell to write it to the file you want, or `man perl` to find out how to make Perl edit in-place.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `grep` to remove the lines.

`grep -B1 -A1 PATTERN file | grep -vFf- file`

First, you can get the line before and after PATTERN with `-B1` and `-A1`.  Then you can pipe that three line result to `grep -v` which will print every non matching line.

- `-f-` takes the patterns from STDIN, and is the same as `-f /dev/stdin`
- `-F` tells grep to interpret the input patterns as fixed strings and not regexes

But you can also turn the output of grep into sed commands to comment out the matching lines:

`grep -A1 -B1 -n PATTERN file | sed -e 's/[^0-9].*$//' -e 's|$|s-^-//-|' | sed -f- file`

What that does is turn the numbered `grep -n` output into `4s-^-//-` ... that is a sed command to comment out line 4, and then pipes those commands created from grep to sed.

Comment: Removes, doesn't comment.

Comment: @slim - now it does.